# Figuring out broadcasting shape in numpy

Tags: python, numpy, array-broadcasting

I understand the basics of `numpy` (Pandas) broadcasting but got stuck on this simple example:

```
x = np.arange(5) 
y = np.random.uniform(size = (2,5)) 
z = x*y 
print(z.shape) #(2,5)
```

My understanding of the z shape is that you had a `(1,5)` array multiplied with a `(2,5)` array, the trailing dimension for 5 is equal so you end up with a `2x5` array. Okay that sounds good. My problem is why is `x.shape = (5,)`? Isn't it one-dimensional so it's really `1x5`?

Comment: In `numpy` a one-dimensional array really has just one dimension, and the shape is a single element tuple, e.g. `(5,)`.  When broadcasting `numpy` adds leading dimensions as needed, so this will be expanded as needed to (1,5), (1,1,5), etc.

Comment: Don't forget that in python, a single element list is written as `[n]` and a single element tuple as `(n,)`. https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#tuples-and-sequences.  The shape of an array is a tuple.

Answer (score 1):

`NumPy` 1D array like `x` gives you shape such as `(5,)` without reshaping. If you want to treat it as 1 column matrix of shape `1x5` then do `np.arange(5).reshape(1,5)`

Comment: How come 1-D arrays are formatted as (# , )? I think this is what is throwing me off. I'm used to viewing it comparing AxBx format so would it look like this? :

(3,) =                 3 

(1,3) =   1 x 3 

(2,3,3) = 2 x 3 x 3

Comment: Usually we talk about a 2d array shape as (rows, columns).  So `(1,5)` would be a single row, 5 columns, (5,1) is 5 rows, 1 column, or a single column array.  For broadcasting purposes a (5,) is treated the same as a (1,5).

Answer (score 1):

The broadcasting rules are:

```
Add leading singleton dimensions as needed to match number of dimensions
Scale any singleton dimensions to match dimension values
Raise error dimensions can't be matched
```

With your `x` and `y`:

```
(5,) * (2,5)
(1,5) * (2,5)          # add the leading 1
(2,5) * (2,5)          # scale the 1
=> (2,5)
```

If `y` was (5,2), it would raise an error, because `(1,5)` cannot be paired with `(5,2)`.  But `(5,1)` is ok, because `(1,5) * (5,1) => (5,5)`.