# Is there a function that can apply NumPy's broadcasting rules to a list of shapes and return the final shape?

Tags: python, numpy, array-broadcasting

This is *not* a question about how broadcasting works (i.e., it's not a duplicate of [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53475472/figuring-out-broadcasting-shape-in-numpy) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11178179/numpy-array-broadcasting-rules)).

I would just like find a function that can apply NumPy's broadcasting rules to a list of shapes and return the final shape, for example:

```py
>>> broadcast_shapes([6], [4, 2, 3, 1], [2, 1, 1])
[4, 2, 3, 6]
```

Thanks!

Comment: `np.broadcast_arrays` will broadcast the arrays against each other.  You could take the shape of any one of the returned arrays.  It returns actual arrays, but since they are broadcasted it shouldn't be particularly expensive; they'll all be views of the originals.

Comment: `broadcast_arrays` uses `np.lib.stride_tricks._broadcast_shape(*args)` to get the target shape.  Using that directly might be a bit faster, but it is flagged private.  It in turn uses `np.broadcast`.   I haven't used any of these much, but I suspect `broadcast_arrays` is the simplest/safest to use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is another direct implementation which happens to beat the others on the example. Honorable mention goes to @hpaulj's with @Warren Weckesser's hack which is almost as fast and much more concise:

```
def bs_pp(*shapes):
    ml = max(shapes, key=len)
    out = list(ml)
    for l in shapes:
        if l is ml:
            continue
        for i, x in enumerate(l, -len(l)):
            if x != 1 and x != out[i]:
                if out[i] != 1:
                    raise ValueError
                out[i] = x
    return (*out,)

def bs_mq1(*shapes):
    max_rank = max([len(shape) for shape in shapes])
    shapes = [[1] * (max_rank - len(shape)) + shape for shape in shapes]
    final_shape = [1] * max_rank
    for shape in shapes:
        for dim, size in enumerate(shape):
            if size != 1:
                final_size = final_shape[dim]
                if final_size == 1:
                    final_shape[dim] = size
                elif final_size != size:
                    raise ValueError("Cannot broadcast these shapes")
    return (*final_shape,)

import numpy as np

def bs_mq2(*shapes):
    max_rank = max([len(shape) for shape in shapes])
    shapes = np.array([[1] * (max_rank - len(shape)) + shape
                      for shape in shapes])
    shapes[shapes==1] = -1
    final_shape = shapes.max(axis=0)
    final_shape[final_shape==-1] = 1
    return (*final_shape,)

def bs_hp_ww(*shapes):
    return np.broadcast(*[np.empty(shape + [0,], int) for shape in shapes]).shape[:-1]

L = [6], [4, 2, 3, 1], [2, 1, 1]

from timeit import timeit

print('pp:       ', timeit(lambda: bs_pp(*L), number=10_000)/10)
print('mq 1:     ', timeit(lambda: bs_mq1(*L), number=10_000)/10)
print('mq 2:     ', timeit(lambda: bs_mq2(*L), number=10_000)/10)
print('hpaulj/ww:', timeit(lambda: bs_hp_ww(*L), number=10_000)/10)

assert bs_pp(*L) == bs_mq1(*L) and bs_pp(*L) == bs_mq2(*L) and bs_pp(*L) == bs_hp_ww(*L)
```

Sample run:

```
pp:        0.0021552839782088993
mq 1:      0.00398325570859015
mq 2:      0.01497043427079916
hpaulj/ww: 0.003267909213900566
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple implementation, just in case someone needs it (it might help understand broadcasting). I would prefer using a NumPy function though.

```py
def broadcast_shapes(*shapes):
    max_rank = max([len(shape) for shape in shapes])
    shapes = [[1] * (max_rank - len(shape)) + shape for shape in shapes]
    final_shape = [1] * max_rank
    for shape in shapes:
        for dim, size in enumerate(shape):
            if size != 1:
                final_size = final_shape[dim]
                if final_size == 1:
                    final_shape[dim] = size
                elif final_size != size:
                    raise ValueError("Cannot broadcast these shapes")
    return final_shape
```

**Edit**

I timed this function against a few other answers, and it turned out to be the fastest (**edit**, Paul Panzer wrote an even faster function, see his answer, I added it to the list below):

```
%timeit bs_pp(*shapes) # Peter Panzer's answer
2.33 µs ± 10.2 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)

%timeit broadcast_shapes1(*shapes)  # this answer
4.21 µs ± 11.2 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)

%timeit broadcast_shapes2(*shapes) # my other answer with shapes.max(axis=0)
12.8 µs ± 67.3 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)

%timeit broadcast_shapes3(*shapes) # user2357112's answer
18 µs ± 26.9 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)

%timeit broadcast_shapes4(*shapes) # hpaulj's answer
18.1 µs ± 263 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

Answer (score 1):

As of NumPy 1.20, there's a [`numpy.broadcast_shapes`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.broadcast_shapes.html) function that does exactly what you're looking for. (It's documented as taking tuples instead of lists, so you should probably pass it tuples just to be safe, but it accepts lists in practice.)

```
In [1]: import numpy

In [2]: numpy.broadcast_shapes((6,), (4, 2, 3, 1), (2, 1, 1))
Out[2]: (4, 2, 3, 6)
```

---

For previous versions, you could broadcast a single 0-dimensional array to each target shape and then broadcast all the results against each other:

```
def broadcast_shapes(*shapes):
    base = numpy.array(0)
    broadcast1 = [numpy.broadcast_to(base, shape) for shape in shapes]
    return numpy.broadcast(*broadcast1).shape
```

This avoids allocating large amounts of memory for large shapes. Needing to create arrays at all feels kind of silly, though.

Comment: Interesting, thanks @user2357112. Are you sure `broadcast_to()` and `broadcast()` don't actually allocate memory? Do they just return views?

Comment: @MiniQuark: `broadcast_to` makes a view. `broadcast` returns a "broadcast object", not an array, and the broadcast object doesn't involve problematic allocations either.

Comment: At least on my machine, they just return views. `a = np.broadcast_to(base,[4,2,3,6])` -> `a.strides = (0, 0, 0, 0)`.

Comment: @Warren's 'hack' (comment to my answer) is faster.

Answer (score 0):

```
In [120]: shapes = [6], [4, 2, 3, 1], [2, 1, 1]                                 
In [121]: arrs = np.broadcast_arrays(*[np.empty(shape,int) for shape in shapes])
     ...:                                                                       
In [122]: [a.shape for a in arrs]                                               
Out[122]: [(4, 2, 3, 6), (4, 2, 3, 6), (4, 2, 3, 6)]

In [124]: np.lib.stride_tricks._broadcast_shape(*[np.empty(shape,int) for shape 
     ...: in shapes])                                                           
Out[124]: (4, 2, 3, 6)

In [131]: np.broadcast(*[np.empty(shape,int) for shape in shapes]).shape        
Out[131]: (4, 2, 3, 6)
```

The second times quite a bit faster, 4.79 µs vs 42.4 µs.  Third is a tad faster.

As I first commented, I started with `broadcast_arrays`, and looked at the code.  That me to `_broadcast_shape`, and then to `np.broadcast`.

Comment: Thanks @hpaulj. Won't these solutions allocate RAM for the `empty()` arrays? If I want to use huge output shapes, it might break, right?

Comment: OS-level allocation laziness probably mitigates some of the problems with the memory allocation involved here, but it still seems like a bad idea to request all this memory.

Comment: Here's a hack to avoid the memory allocation of the last option: `np.broadcast(*[np.empty(shape + [0,], int) for shape in shapes]).shape[:-1]`

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser Clever! And actually rather fast it seems.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the shapes can actually be broadcasted, then this works:

```py
def broadcast_shapes(*shapes):
    max_rank = max([len(shape) for shape in shapes])
    shapes = np.array([[1] * (max_rank - len(shape)) + shape
                      for shape in shapes])
    shapes[shapes==1] = -1
    final_shape = shapes.max(axis=0)
    final_shape[final_shape==-1] = 1
    return final_shape
```

If you assume there's no empty dimension, then the `-1` hack is not necessary:

```py
def broadcast_shapes(*shapes):
    max_rank = max([len(shape) for shape in shapes])
    shapes = np.array([[1] * (max_rank - len(shape)) + shape
                      for shape in shapes])
    return shapes.max(axis=0)
```